# Solving $\sin(\arccos(x/2))$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, triangles

I am having trouble solving $\sin(\arccos(x/2))$. I can see how to do this equation when the question is just $\arccos(x)$ but having the $x/2$ is throwing me off a bit. I still know one side of the triangle is $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ but can't figure out how to go from there.

Comment: "Solving" is not the right word. You should have used "Simplify".

Answer (score 3):

let $\arccos(x/2) = t.$  then $0 \le t \le \pi$ and $\cos t = x/2.$  therefore $\sin t = \sqrt{1 - \cos^2 t} = \sqrt{1 - x^2/4}$

Comment: Yes I get that but I'm trying to picture this in terms of a triangle.

Comment: make a right angle triangle with one of the angle $t,$  opposite side to this angle is the side $x/2$ and make the hypotenuse $1.$  by the pythagorass theorem, the adjacent side is $\sqrt{1-x^2/4}.$ so $\cos t = adj/hyp.$

Comment: You can produce $\arcsin x$, $\arccos x$, and $\arctan x$ by typing \arcsin x, \arccos x, and \arctan x, respectively, in math mode.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, thanks. i will remember that.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\arccos\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right) = \theta$.  Then $\cos\theta = \dfrac{x}{2}$, where $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$.  Since $\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
\sin^2\theta & = 1 - \cos^2\theta\\
             & = 1 - \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2\\
             & = 1 - \frac{x^2}{4}\\
             & = \frac{4 - x^2}{4}
\end{align*}
Taking square roots yields 
$$|\sin\theta| = \frac{\sqrt{4 - x^2}}{2}$$
Since $\sin\theta \geq 0$ if $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$, 
$$\sin\theta = \frac{\sqrt{4 - x^2}}{2}$$

**Note:**  You expressed an interest in determining the answer by drawing a triangle.  If we let $\arccos\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right) = \theta$, we can draw a right triangle with acute angle $\theta$ with adjacent leg of length $|x|$ and hypotenuse of length $2$.  By the Pythagorean Theorem, the opposite leg then has length $\sqrt{4 - x^2}$, as shown in the diagram below.  We can then use the right triangle to determine that $$\sin\theta = \frac{\sqrt{4 - x^2}}{2}$$

[image: arccosine_triangle]

**Caveats:**  I have drawn a right triangle in the first quadrant.  However, the triangle collapses to a line segment if $\theta = 0, \dfrac{\pi}{2}, \text{or}~\pi$.  Also, if $\dfrac{\pi}{2} < \theta < \pi$, the right triangle would be drawn in the second quadrant, which is why I denoted the length of the adjacent leg by $|x|$ rather than $x$.  The algebraic argument given above does not require such caveats.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Put $p=x/2$ and do what you normally do to reduce $\sin(\arccos(p))$. Then put $p=x/2$ back in.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\theta = \arccos(\frac x2)$. Then $0 \le \theta \le \pi$ and $\theta$ corresponds to the point $(x,y) = (x,\sqrt{4-x^2})$ with amplitude $r = 2$. Note that the y-coordinate is non negative since $\theta$ is in quadrants I and II.

It follows that
$\sin(\arccos(\frac x2)) = \sin \theta = \dfrac yr = \dfrac{\sqrt{4-x^2}}{2}.$

Comment: @N.F.Taussig thanks.